# Requirements for coauthoring in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019, co-authoring

We have around 50 power point presentations and we want to coauthor them. we have around 30 users. we want to invest in SharePoint 2019, but does SharePoint server 2019 support coauthoring? If so, then what is the exact requirements to have coauthoring in SharePoint 2019?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint Server 2019 supports co-authoring. The exact requirements and setup details are too much for an answer in this site, though.

Take a look at the Microsoft Documentation. This page is the starting point specifically for co-authoring on on-premises SharePoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/co-authoring-overview

Answer (score 1):

you can also read this article about what you need to co-author a document:
[Document collaboration and co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4)